# Getting StackOverFlowError

Tags: java

I have created class.When I run the main method I get stack overflow error at the line `if(this.compareTo(other) > 0)` . Not sure I am doing the `compareTo` method right for generics.
What is the correct way ?

What may be wrong in the code?

```
public class StackMin<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private static class StackNode<T extends Comparable> implements Comparable {

        private T data;
        private StackNode<T> next;

        public StackNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object other) {

            if(this.compareTo(other) > 0)
                return 1;
            else if(this.compareTo(other) == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.data.toString();
        }
    }

    private StackNode<T> top = null;
    private Stack<StackNode<T>> min = new Stack<StackNode<T>>();


    public void push(T data) {

        StackNode node = new StackNode(data);

        if ( top == null) {
            top = node;
            min.push(node);
        }
        else {
            if ( node.compareTo(top) < 0) {
                min.push(node);
            }
            top.next = top;
            top = node;
        }

    }

    public T pop() throws EmptyStackException {

        if (top == null) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }

        T data = top.data;
        top = top.next;
        min.pop();
        return data;
    }

    public T min() {
        return min.peek().data;

    }

    public boolean empty() {

        return (top == null);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        StackMin min = new StackMin();
        try {
            min.push(10);
            min.push(9);
            min.push(6);
            min.push(7);
            min.pop();
            System.out.println(min.min());
            min.pop();
            System.out.println(min.min());
            min.pop();
            System.out.println(min.min());
            min.pop();
            System.out.println(min.min());
            min.pop();
            System.out.println(min.min());
        } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  It is hard to predict what you are doing wrong without it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some of your code so that we can understand better about your problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: When i add code I get below error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: @Harish You should add a [mcve] with the emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: Make sure you have set `exit entry` if you use `recurring` way.

Comment: My guess is that you're calling `compareTo` from within your `compareTo` method. Try debugging into your code, and you're likely to spot the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it . was calling compareTo from compareTo

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object other) {

        if(this.data.compareTo(((StackNode)other).data) > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (this.data.compareTo(((StackNode)other).data) == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```